# (Reference request) higher order Hölder spaces on riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a reference regarding the higher (than the first) order Hölder spaces on Riemannian manifolds. I am aware that defining Hölder spaces of form $C^{0,\alpha}$ is not an issue even between two metric spaces. However, so far, I haven't even seen a definition of higher order Hölder spaces outside of the Euclidean setting.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full blown answer, but still it may help a bit:

I developed a bit of this in my PhD thesis that was published in a [book series](https://link.springer.com/book/10.2991/978-94-6239-003-4), see also [my website](https://www.jaapeldering.nl/research.php) for freely available thesis and book preprint. The contents is in appendix C and specifically used in Lemma C.10 to estimate the $C^{k,\alpha}$ norm of a flow on a Riemmanian manifold (of bounded geometry), given that the first derivative of it satisfies an exponential growth estimate. I didn't define spaces of $C^{k,\alpha}$ functions really, as I didn't define proper $C^{k,\alpha}$ norms, see the discussion around the lemma.

I'm not aware of other (earlier) results in the literature, but to be honest I haven't searched exhaustively for it.